# Como calcular un campo nuevo sin modificar la tabla original SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-management

Bueno lo que me gustaria hacer es crear una columna nueva al calcularla con datos de otras columnas pero sin modificar la tabla original.

Bueno planteo un ejemplo... tengo una tabla en la que guardo las materias, y sus calificaciones por parcial algo como esto:

```
Materia                C1        C2      C3      C4
Ciencias Naturales     10         8       9      10
Matematicas             6         7       6       9
Geografia              10        10      10      10
Español                 8         8       9       9    
Ingles                  7         7       6       5
```

Y quiero hacer una vista o sp el cual calcule el promedio en una nueva columna y del promedio crear otra nueva columna que por medio de una condicion determine si esta aprobado o no, pero estas columnas solo mostrarlas dentro del sp o vista sin tener que modificar los valores de la tabla original

Comment: qué haz intentado? se lee sencillo, pero sería bueno ver el código para resolver el problema.

Comment: @lsanchezo No he intentado nada porque no tengo idea que puedo hacer, ya que como mencione no debo de modificar la tabla original al agregar otra columna ademas de que no tengo permisos. Por eso di como ejemplo sencillo multiplicar los valores de dos columnas para generar otra pero aun asi no se como generarla

Comment: ¿Como pretendes agregar una columna sin modificar la tabla? Es como decir que quieres volar sin elevarte. Tienes opciones como crear una columna computada o generar una vista o un procedimiento que tengan esa columna pero ya no estaría directamente en la tabla sino en un objeto que dependa de la misma.

Comment: @LuisCazares Exactamente, osea puedo generar ya sea un sp o una vista y ahi aguegar la columna a la tabla pero que solamente este ahi, en mi tabla original fuera del sp o vista esta columna generada no este.

Comment: ya lo intentaste con una vista?
o porqué no podría ser una vista?

Comment: @MrDonPh0x aun no, por eso quiero ver como se usaria ya sea con un sp o con una vista porque aun soy nuevo en el manejo de sql y me gustaria saber como puedo realizarlo

Comment: No está muy claro el planteamiento. Si quieres multiplicar valores solo usa `SELECT (CANTIDAD * PRECIO) AS TOTAL FROM ...`. Ahora, si necesitas almacenar ese dato, definitivamente tienes que crear un campo adicional, sea en la tabla original o en una tabla intermedia almacenando el oid de la tabla original con el total, por ejemplo. Danos más detalles para imaginarnos el escenario.

Comment: @DjCrazy Listo, creo que con ese escenario se puede entender un poco mejor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero. **SSMS2018** no es más que, un programa cliente que se conecta a un servidor. No identifica nada en cuanto a Código SQL.

Para saber tú servidor, puedes usar `Select @@version`. Adicionalmente hay otro dato importante, que es el nivel de compatibilidad de la base de datos, que te puede generar problemas y/o errores aunque estés en un servidor X, donde X suele ser (2005, 2008, 2008r2, 2012, 2012r2, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 y 2022). O incluso la versión....pero eso será otra guerra. Por tanto no digas, que tienes SSMS2018. muestra en las preguntas, siempre el número que te devuelva **Select @@version.**

Escenario:

```
Create table Materias (Materia varchar(50), c1 tinyint, c2 tinyint, c3 tinyint, c4 tinyint)
Insert into Materias(Materia, c1, c2, c3, c4)
Values
('Ciencias Naturales', 10,  8,  9, 10),
('Matematicas'       ,  6,  7,  6,  9),
('Geografia'         , 10, 10, 10, 10),
('Español'           ,  8,  8,  9,  9),    
('Ingles'            ,  7,  3,  2,  5);
```

He cambiado, las notas de inglés para poder suspender.

**Opción Vista**

```
Create View dbo.MateriasView As
Select
      Materia
    , c1
    , c2
    , c3
    , c4
    , (C1+C2+C3+C4)/4 AS Promedio
    , case when (C1+C2+C3+C4)/4 >= 5 
        then 'APROBADO'
        else 'SUSPENSO'
        End as Resultado
from Materias ;
```

No es más que una Select y en las columnas adicionales a la tabla, realiza operaciónes devolviendo el resultado en nuevas columnas.

La tabla no ha cambiado. Pero la vista, me devuelve los datos que necesito.

```
Select * from dbo.Materias;
Select * from dbo.MateriasView;
```

[image: Res1]

Por tanto en la vista, puedo hacer los cálculos que necesite sin, modificar la estructura de la tabla.

**Columna Calculada**

```
Alter Table dbo.Materias
Add PromedioCalculado As ((C1+C2+C3+C4)/4);
```

Ahora si he modificado la estructura de la tabla, indicándole al motor que esa columna nueva, se basa en un cálculo que realizará, cada vez que consulte los datos.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.materias;
```

[image: Res2]

Esta columna no almacena los valores, se calcula en tiempo de ejecución.

**Columna persistida**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Materias
Add PromedioPersistido As ((C1+C2+C3+C4)/4) Persisted;
```

Este tipo de columna, si cambia la estructura de la tabla, y además anota físicamente los datos. Ya no necesita calcularlos al vuelo, para cada select que se lo solicite.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.materias;
```

[image: Res3]

En cualquiera de las 3 opciones, la manera de extraer los datos, no es más que una `Select`, y por tanto puede tener cabida dentro de un procedimiento o no.

Comment: Excelente, te lo agradezco mucho esto es lo que necesitaba saber, y una pregunta si quiero sacar un resultado de una columna con un if como se hace?, es decir si en mi columna donde saque el promedio tiene 9 o 10 en una columna nueva agregar que tendran reconocimiento, y en caso contrario que no tendran reconocimiento

Comment: If no Case. Lo mismo que ibas a hacer con un if, lo haces con un case......`Select col1, col2, case when ...laexpresión.... then resultado else otroresultado end As NombreColumna`

Comment: Pero en caso de que son varias condiciones con distintas expresiones, ejemplo si la expresion primera que ingresa no se cumple pasar a otra expresion y sino se cumple pasar a otra expresion

Comment: Busca case en la documentacion. Admite anidamientos. Case when expr1 then x else case when expr2 then else case when...........end end end as column